# How to favourite the twitter feed?

Tags: android

In my application I have one **expandable list view** which displays twitter feeds.

When the user clicks the list view then the child view opens in that I am having button called **favourite**, by clicking **favourite** button the feed in the list view should be add in to that corresponding twitter account.

I searched lot in web but I can't able to find any good tutorial or link. I don't have any basic idea for twitter.

Please provide me some suggestions how to do it.

Comment: To clarify: You are logged in as a twitter user with the app? And the "groups" of the expandable list view are the tweets, then each one will have one child view which will have a favorite button. Then, when you click favorite, it should make the API request to twitter to favorite that tweet?

Comment: and how are you interacting with the API? making REST requests directly or using a library? Which library?

Comment: I am not using any kind of library or REST request,basically i dont know what and how to use.if you give some suggestion its quite usefull for me